# Whi isnt my Heroku Deployed spring-boot/angular/aws-rds application not contacting server on mobile devices?

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, mobile, angular7, okta

I have set up and successfully deployed a spring-boot application storing data in a aws-rds, as well as a angular 7 client-side application that uses Okta for authentication. All deployed on Heroku. On my computer, everything works fine, but on any mobile devices (iphone, ipad, android phone), the application is not reaching (or even seeming to attempt) to reach the server application. I don't even know where to start debugging. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you’re not using localhost in your configuration files. Does it still work if you reboot your computer (which will kill the servers running on localhost)?

Comment: These are both running on a deployed application, and i'm trying on my phone, which I'm not sure how they could be affecting each other. They don't point to any of the same locations with the exception of the RDS

Comment: Nevermind. I'm an idiot... it was still pointing to the localhost, which was running on my machine. I have a misunderstanding of how environment.ts and prod.environment.ts works. Time to learn that. haha